# Identifying the header file in a C program

Tags: c, header-files

I am fairly new to C.

I am trying to compile a C program found at this link (based on a scientific publication):

https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fncomms11219/MediaObjects/41467_2016_BFncomms11219_MOESM262_ESM.txt

but am experiencing difficulty.

The issue arises because the custom header file has been placed with the C program itself for some odd reason.

I need to know where the header file ends so that I can paste the entire header file into a fresh script to allow successful compilation.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since you're new to C, be advised that this code from springer.com is easily the worst code in any programming language that I have seen in the last 20 years. I have heard that scientific code often tends to be poor quality, but this one takes the cake. Whatever you do, don't use it as a model of how you should write any of your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to split the `.txt` file into two files.

Lines 1 through 1974 should go into a `.c` file.
Lines 1975 through 3484 should go into `polygyny14.h`.
There are a few lines at the end of the `.txt` file that can be discarded as they don't appear to contain valid C code.

Comment: You will then also have to re-order a function that is used before its definition.

Comment: It is kinda extraordinary that there seems to be a block of 50 printing statements that should be in a loop (lines 1041-1090).  There's also a block of 50 consecutive statements `fg1 = fopen(…); … fg50 = fopen(…);` (lines 314-363), and later another block of 50 statements `fclose(fg1); … fclose(fg50);` (lines 1923-1972) — that sort of thing leaves me wondering about the quality of the software.  When I downloaded the document, I got Mac-style (^M or `\r` only) line endings for most of the document.  It was easy enough to fix, but a bit curious.  There's no error checking on the file handling.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why this was done. Since for loops are fine to use in languages like C, such contstructs would be more succinct and readable.